# How to do code splitting using Svelte without Sapper

Tags: svelte

How do you do code splitting with Svelte?

(I see that you could do it using Sapper, but I don´t want to take a dependency on a node backend)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Code splitting is actually a fancy name for dynamic imports. Here's how to do it with Rollup (you'll also get killer tree-shaking in the process!).

Reminder on dynamic imports:

```js
// "normal" static ES import
//
// - statically analytisable
// - must be called at top level
// - will be greedily resolved (and most often inlined) by your bundler
//
import Foo from './Foo.svelte'

// dynamic import
//
// - called like a function
// - returns a promise
// - default export is accessible on key `default` of the result
// - will be bundled into its own chunk by your bundler (hence code splitting)
//
import('./Foo.svelte').then(module => {
  const cmp = module.default
  console.log(module.myNamedExport)
})
```

Note that dynamic imports are a native ES feature, like normal imports. This means they are supported natively by non-outdated browsers.

Rollup has been supporting "code splitting from dynamic imports" for a while (see [docs](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#code-splitting)).

So, if you want code splitting in your project, it's mainly a matter of configuring Rollup so that it chunks dynamic imports (another option would be to resolve and inline them, which would not result in code splitting).

Here are the steps to do this, starting from Svelte's [official template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template).

1. change `output.format` to `'es'`
2. change `output.file` to `output.dir` (e.g. `'public/build'`)
3. change the `<script>` tag in `index.html` to point to the new entry point `/build/main.js`, and use `type="module"`
4. write some code with dynamic imports
5. add support for legacy browsers

### Rollup config: `output.format` and `output.dir`

Not all output formats available in Rollup can support dynamic imports. Default from the Svelte template, `iife` does not, so we need to change.

`output.format: 'es'` won't rewrite `import` statements in your code. This means we will rely on the browser's native module loader. All browsers supports ES `import` or dynamic `import(...)` these days, and legacy browsers can be polyfilled.

Another option could be, for example, `output.format: 'system'`, for [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), but that would require us from shipping the third-party module loader in addition to our code.

We also need to change `output.file` to `output.dir` because code splitting will not produce a single `bundle.js` file, but multiple chunks. (And you can't write separate files to a single file, obviously...)

So, here's the relevant part of our Rollup config now:

```js
  input: 'src/main.js', // not changed
  output: {
    format: 'es',
    dir: 'public/build/',
  },
```

If you run `yarn build` (or `npm run build`) at this point, you'll see that you application now gets split in multiple `.js` files in the `/public/build/ directory.

### index.html

We now need to change the `<script>` tag in our `index.html` (located in `public/index.html, in the Svelte template) to consume this.

```html
    <script defer type="module" src="/build/main.js"></script>
```

First, we need to change the `src` from `bundle.js` (which was our old `output.file`) to the new entry point of our application. Since our entry point in the Rollup config (`input`) is `src/main.js`, the main entry point of our app will be written to `main.js` (configurable with Rollup's [`entryFileNames`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputentryfilenames) option).

Since our code is now full of ES `import` statements (because we're using `output.format='esm'`), we also need to change the type of script from `script` (the default) to `module` by adding the `type="module"` attribute to our script tag.

That's it for modern browsers, you now have fully working code splitting support!

### Actually split your application

Code splitting support is not enough to get actual code splitting. It just makes it possible. You still need to separate dynamic chunks from the rest (main) of your application.

You do this by writing dynamic imports in your code. For example:

```js
import('./Foo.svelte')
  .then(module => module.default)
  .then(Foo => { /* do something with Foo */ })
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

This will result in Rollup creating a `Foo-[hash].js` chunk (configurable with [`chunkFileNames`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputchunkfilenames) option), and possibly another chunk for dependencies of `Foo.svelte` that are shared with other components.

In the browser, this file will only get loaded when the `import('./Foo.svelte')` statement is encountered in your code (lazy loading).

[image]

(Notice, in the waterfall, how `Foo` and `Cmp` -- a common dep -- get loaded long after the page load, indicated by the vertical red bar.)

### Legacy browsers

Edge (before recently becoming Chrome) does not support dynamic imports. Normal ES imports, yes, but dynamic `import(...)` no. That's usually why you have to include some polyfill for outdated browsers.

One solution, like in the [rollup-starter-code-splitting](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-starter-code-splitting) example, is to use a third party module loader (e.g. SytemJS) in the browser.

Another, probably simpler, solution available these days is to use the [`dimport`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dimport) package. It polyfills support for ES imports and dynamic imports as needed by the host browser.

In order to use it, we're replacing our `<script>` tag in `index.html` with the following:

```html
    <script defer type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/dimport?module"
        data-main="/build/main.js"></script>
    <script defer type="nomodule" src="https://unpkg.com/dimport/nomodule"
        data-main="/build/main.js"></script>
```

And voilà. Full fledged code splitting. (Simpler than you thought, isn't it?)

### Complete example

Here's a [complete example](https://github.com/rixo/svelte-template-hot/tree/example-code-splitting) implementing all the different bits covered in this answer. You might be particularly interested in [this commit](https://github.com/rixo/svelte-template-hot/commit/f4c300c4d0a88161767345ff521f7be3ada5c901).

Attention! Please notice that the example lives on the `example-code-splitting` branch of the repository, not `master`. You'll need to checkout the right branch if you clone the repo!

Example usage:

```sh
# install
npx degit rixo/svelte-template-hot#example-code-splitting svelte-app
cd svelte-app
yarn # or npm install

# dev
yarn dev

# build
yarn build
# serve build
yarn start
```

Comment: Best answer ever! Thx.

Comment: @rixo Thanks a lot. I am using your template  for splitting. When going to production caching is the issue. do you have solution for this : https://github.com/sveltejs/template/issues/39 `main.js` cached by browser. want to main.js in index.thml with dynamic hash.

Comment: I use HTTP expiry value of 1 day for the _index.html_ (front/proxy server configuration), and also use cache busting strategy (bundler configuration) so that _main.js_ script _src_ is different every time a deploy occurs.

Answer (score 5):

This repo might be a good place to start https://github.com/Rich-Harris/rollup-svelte-code-splitting