# How to generate separate js files when using [slug].svelte

Tags: svelte, sapper

I am using sapper to build a site that consists of many sub-pages that each use a different svelte component (with svg visualizations) and I plan to export it as a static site. Right now I am using a [slug].svelte file to get easy routing for the sub-pages.

My problem is that when I export the site, it generates one single huge [slug]....js file that seems to contain all the data for the visualizations of the sub-pages. Is there a way to get smaller/single js files for each sub-page when using [slug].svelte?

It seems I could just make my routes manually by making a folder for each sub-page and that way generate separate js files. Maybe the problem is that I am importing all the components in a single `_select.svelte` file to select the right svelte component for each sub-page. I was trying to import the components dynamically in hoping that this would generate a different js file for each sub-page, but then the static site generation won't work. I am probably doing something horribly wrong here...

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code-split entry points are created in two cases:

- A `.svelte` or `.js` file is being treated as a route (as in `[slug].svelte`)
- A *dynamic import* is used

It sounds like you want the second option:

```html
<script>
  const imports = {
    a: () => import('./A.svelte'),
    b: () => import('./B.svelte'),
    c: () => import('./C.svelte')
  };

  export let component = 'a';
</script>

{#await imports[component]() then module}
  <svelte:component this={module.default}/>
{/await}
```

[Demo here](https://svelte.dev/repl/ec6f6b61329f4f43ae049464d73d8158?version=3.23.1).

Note that you have to spell out all the different `import(...)` possibilities — you can't do this sort of thing...

```html
<script>
  const imports = {
    a: './A.svelte',
    b: './B.svelte',
    c: './C.svelte'
  };

  export let component = 'a';
  $: promise = import(imports[component]);
</script>

{#await promise then module}
  <svelte:component this={module.default}/>
{/await}
```

...because the bundler needs to be able to 'see' which files are dynamically imported when the app is built.

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much, this is the perfect solution! I love Svelte and Sapper, such an elegant way to build websites. I am still new to web development but I enjoy every bit of it because of this great piece of work!

Answer (score 0):

There are two different techniques, and I do not know which one suites best. A svelte app is usually shipped as a single `bundles.js` file. That would contain all code that you have imported anywhere on your svelte files and it can be big.

If you want to optimize the load time of your app, you may be looking for code splitting (dynamic imports). Here's a good answer on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60026703/105224

Another way is splitting the project into different svelte apps using multiple rollup configurations (simply export an array of configs instead of a single one). Those apps are totally independent and don't share state. But that looks to me like mixing traditional (express-) routes (each routes has its own html) with svelte. I think that's more interesting if you want to enhance existing (static) pages with dynamic behavior.

Comment: Thank you! I will check out code-splitting in svelte, although I wonder if there is a preferred way to do it with sapper.