# Svelte: dynamically import icon in component

Tags: javascript, font-awesome, svelte

I have a component in Svelte where I pass the icon name, and want to render this icon, but I want import needed icon dynamically from font-awesome.

```html
<script>
  import Icon from 'fa-svelte';

  export let iconName;

  let icon;

  async function loadIcon() {
    let { fa } = await import(`@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/${iconName}`)
    icon = fa
  }

  loadIcon();
</script>

<Icon icon={icon}>
```

But this is does not work and `icon` variable is undefined. Am I doing it wrong, or this is not possible to implement in this way?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is a good idea as you load and wait for the icon each time the Icon component is mounted. It probably doesn't work because the svelte adds all dependencies to the bundle file and here it doesn't know what to add. So I guess, it fails because the svelte app doesn't know where to import from at runtime.

Comment: This is probably a bundler thing rather than a Svelte thing. Can you post more details? Which bundler are you using? What error are you seeing? Does the import promise resolve, or not? Etc

Comment: Dynamic import need a change in rollup default svelte config : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60024414/how-to-do-code-splitting-using-svelte-without-sapper